# Properties of the constructible closure of a set

Tags: set-theory

Given any set $A$ define

- $L_0(A)=\{A\}\cup \operatorname{tr cl}(A)$
- $L_{\alpha+1}(A)=\mathcal{D}^+(L_\alpha(A))$
- $L_\gamma (A)=\bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma}L_\alpha(A)$ if $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal.

where $\mathcal{D}^+(L_\alpha(A))$ denotes the subsets of $L_{\alpha}(A)$ defined with parameters in $L_{\alpha}(A)$ .

I'm having struggles with the proofs of the following two facts:

- $L_\alpha\subset L_\alpha(A)$ for every $\alpha$
- $|L_\alpha(A)|=\max\{|\operatorname{tr cl}(A)|,|\alpha|\}$

Could somebody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure, that these are 'facts'? It seems to me, that $L_\alpha \subseteq L_\alpha(A)$ might fail, if by $\mathcal D^+(M)$ you denote all subset of $M$ definable with parameters from $M$ in the structure $(M, \in)$.

Comment: Oh... Do you know some easy counterexample?

Comment: Gödel Operations to the rescue...

Comment: Thank you very much @Stefan !!

Comment: You're welcome. I was worried about the step $\alpha \to \alpha+1$ in a case where $L_\alpha(A) \cap \operatorname{Ord} = \alpha$ and $L_\alpha \subsetneq L_\alpha(A)$... Fortunately, the $L_\alpha$ hierarchy is very robust...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim: $L_\alpha \subseteq L_\alpha(A)$ for all $\alpha \in \operatorname{Ord}$.

Proof by induction on $\alpha$. For $\alpha = 0$ and limit ordinals, this is immediate. So let $\alpha = \beta +1$. We have $L_\alpha(A) \cap \operatorname{Ord} \ge L_\alpha \cap \operatorname{Ord} = \alpha$ and thus $\beta \in L_\alpha(A)$. This also yields $L_\beta \in L_\alpha(A)$. Now $L_\alpha$ can be charaterized as the closure of $L_\beta \cup \{L_\beta\}$ under Gödel Operations restricted to subsets of $L_\beta$ (see for example chapter 13 in Jech's 3rd millennium Set Theory). Since $L_\alpha(A)$ is closed under Gödel Operations restricted to subsets of $L_\alpha(A)$, it follows that $L_\alpha \subseteq L_\alpha(A)$. q.e.d.

Now consider $A = \{\emptyset\}$. Then $L_0(A) = \{A\} \cup \operatorname{trcl}(A) = \{ \{\emptyset\}, \emptyset\}$. Thus your 2nd claim fails in this case. However

Claim: $\mid L_\alpha(A) \mid \le \max \{ \mid \operatorname{trcl}(\{A\}) \mid , \mid \alpha \mid, \aleph_0 \}$.

Proof by induction on $\alpha$. Again if $\alpha = 0$ or $\alpha$ is a limit, this is immediate. Let $\alpha = \beta +1$. Then $\mid L_\alpha(A) \mid \le \mid L_\beta(A) \mid \ \cdot \aleph_0 \le \max \{ \mid \operatorname{trcl}(\{A\}) \mid , \mid \beta \mid, \aleph_0 \} = \max \{ \mid \operatorname{trcl}(\{A\}) \mid , \mid \alpha \mid, \aleph_0 \}$. q.e.d.

Comment: It should be pointed that the second claim uses choice. So it might not be true internally to $L(A)$.

Comment: @Stefan Only one thing: I can't see  the argument which allows us to ensure $L_\beta\in L_\alpha(A)$...

Comment: @Ergonvi The function $\beta \mapsto L_\beta$ is $\Delta_1$ and as such absolute between transitive structures. Since $\beta \in L_\alpha(A)$, we have that $L_\beta \in L_\alpha(A)$.

Comment: Thank you once again @Stefan :)